# how to display child and parent JSON data in each row of the list in Sencha using model and store

Tags: json, model, mapping, extjs

My server returning the following nested json. I want to display the fullname and text comes as a each row of the list. like,

**apple Message2**

**apple Message1**

Instead of this, I got one row contains all the data as the following:

**apple Message2 Message1**.

If json may be like this:

```
"packet": {
        "fullname": "apple",
        "wants": {
            "text": "Message 2",
        }
    }
```

we can mention the field in model:

```
fields: [{
    name: 'fullname',
    type: 'string'
}, {
    name: 'text',
    mapping: 'wants.text'
}]
```

But I have array of `wants`, how to access the `wants` array through mapping?

**json String:**

```
"packet": {
    "fullname": "apple",
    "wants": [{
        "text": "Message 2",

    }, {
        "text": "Message 1",
    }]
}
```

**Model:**

```
Ext.define('myApp.model.Packet', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [{
                name: 'fullname',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'text',
                mapping: 'wants[0].text'
            } //Is this right? If right mean how to get next wants.how to iterate?
        ]
    }
});
```

**Store:**

```
Ext.define('myApp.store.WantsStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        model: 'myApp.model.Packet',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'server path',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'packet'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**List:**

```
Ext.define('myappApp.view.WantsList', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'wantslist',
    config: {
        itemCls: 'my-dataview-item',
        loadingText: 'Loading items...',
        emptyText: '<div class="notes-list-empty-text">No Wants found.</div>',
        itemTpl: '<div><p class="list-item-title">{fullname} <span id="time" class="list-item-title">{text}</span></p>'
    }
});
```

Thanks in Advance!